# Unable to override crypto providers in Mono-2.10.8

Tags: c#, .net, mono, cryptography, machine.config

I am unable to map my crypto provider to a name in the machine.config file. At first glance everything appears in order, am I overlooking something silly? I'm using Mono-2.10.8

```
<mscorlib>
    <cryptographySettings>
        <cryptoNameMapping>
            <cryptoClasses>
                <cryptoClass monoMD2="Mono.Security.Cryptography.MD2Managed, Mono.Security, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756" />
                <cryptoClass AesProvider="MyProvider.MyAes, MswlAes, Culture='neutral', PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756, Version=1.0.0.0"/>
            </cryptoClasses>
            <nameEntry name="MD2" class="monoMD2" />
            <nameEntry name="AES" class="AesProvider"/>
            <nameEntry name="AES128" class="AesProvider"/>
            <nameEntry name="AES192" class="AesProvider"/>
            <nameEntry name="AES256" class="AesProvider"/>
            <nameEntry name="Rijndael" class="AesProvider"/>
            <nameEntry name="System.Security.Cryptography.Rijndael" class="AesProvider"/>
            <nameEntry name="System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged" class="AesProvider"/>
            <nameEntry name="System.Security.Cryptography.SymmetricAlgorithm" class="AesProvider"/>
        </cryptoNameMapping>
        <oidMap>
            <oidEntry OID="1.2.840.113549.2.2" name="MD2" />
            <oidEntry OID="1.2.840.113549.2.2" name="Mono.Security.Cryptography.MD2Managed" />
            <oidEntry OID="2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.1" name="AesProvider" />
            <oidEntry OID="2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.2" name="AesProvider" />
            <oidEntry OID="2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.2" name="AesProvider" />
            <oidEntry OID="2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.21" name="AesProvider" />
            <oidEntry OID="2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.22" name="AesProvider" />
            <oidEntry OID="2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.23" name="AesProvider" />
            <oidEntry OID="2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.24" name="AesProvider" />
            <oidEntry OID="2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.3" name="AesProvider" />
            <oidEntry OID="2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.4" name="AesProvider" />
            <oidEntry OID="2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.41" name="AesProvider" />
            <oidEntry OID="2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.42" name="AesProvider" />
            <oidEntry OID="2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.43" name="AesProvider" />
            <oidEntry OID="2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.44" name="AesProvider" />
            <oidEntry OID="2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1" name="AesProvider" />
            <oidEntry OID="2.16.840.1.101.3.4.4" name="AesProvider" />
        </oidMap>
    </cryptographySettings>
</mscorlib>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug that was [fixed](https://github.com/mono/mono/commit/ae5e52145fee2cac7863ce7794d305b1c325fc77#mcs/class/corlib/System.Security.Cryptography/CryptoConfig.cs) (very) recently where new algorithms / oid could be added but **not** replaced. It will be part of future Mono 2.10.x releases. Otherwise your machine.config looks right to me.